# Effects of Generations Living Under 110% Gravity

Tags: biology, anatomy

Human colony on another world, Earth-like but with little oxygen, therefore no ozone*, thus resulting in spending lives within airtight settlements (think the Martian, blown up to the scale of a large enough population for reproduction).
Any answers would be greatly appreciated

*No indigenous life, either

Comment: Your question is currently a little short, please elaborate a little more. What kinds of generations? What species? Under what environment? Is it Earth-like? The more detailed and concise your question, the better.

Comment: Are you interested solely in genetic effects (I assume you're after some kind of evolution, since you mention generations of people) or the physiological effects on a single person over a lifetime spent in 1.1g?

Comment: This question is not about world buidling. It's steam form wrong assumption that Earth gravity is constant on the whole planet. Which is not. If you take equator as base  you can easily find places with stronger gravity where people live for generations.

Comment: Gravity on the Earth's surface varies by around 0.7%, and the OP is talking about a difference of 10%.

Comment: @ALambentEye Apologies for deleting your edit to the post, but the evolutionary pressures that would occur under 1.1g isn't quite what I was looking for, but rather merely the resultant health effects upon settlers. In all honesty, I might re-do this question at a later point to a higher quality. Been away from the website for about a year, little out of practice

Comment: @NFrancis No worries, that was merely my interpretation of your question. Feel free to rewrite your question to contain the phrase 'long-term health effects'.

Answer (score 2):

**Very Little**

Most people have more than the weight difference as excess fat. The change from Earth gravity is so small no noticeable difference would be seen.

Any noticeable changes would only seen statistically with a possible slight increase in heart attacks and strokes from the heart working fractionally harder. Maybe some extra wear on the joints so some possible increased arthritis.